# Using AND in VBA excel with Select case

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a simple function that give me band 1 if value is zero
Band 2 if its between 0 to 150k 
Band 3 if between 150 k to 500k and so on

I only get 1 if value is zero and everything else is 2 , even if I enbter 10 million

Please help

```
Function Band(ARR)

    Select Case ARR

        Case Is = 0
            Band = 1

        Case Is >= 0.1 And ARR <= 150000
            Band = 2

        Case Is >= 150000.01 And ARR <= 500000
            Band = 3

        Case Is >= 500000.01 And ARR <= 1500000
            Band = 4

        Case Is >= 1500000.01
            Band = 5

        Case Else
            Band = 6

    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Short answer is you can't. But you also do not need to. Get rid of the greater than arguments. Select case will short circuit as it finds true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the "To" keyword to specify a range. [See here for more information.](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php)

```
Function Band(arr)
Select Case arr
  Case 0
    Band = 1
  Case 0.01 To 150000
    Band = 2
  Case 150000.01 To 500000
    Band = 3
  Case 500000.01 To 1500000
    Band = 4
  Case Is >= 1500000.01
    Band = 5
  Case Else
    Band = 6
  End Select
End Function
```

Comment: @WillyWild, thank you for pointing out the "Is" keyword was missing.

Answer (score 4):

VBA Select Case 'short-circuits' (i.e. no further cases are examined) once a matching criteria is met so there is no need for And operators.

```
Function Band(ARR)
    Select Case true
        Case ARR < 0
            Band = 6
        Case arr = 0
            Band = 1
        Case arr <= 150000
            Band = 2
        Case arr <= 500000
            Band = 3
        Case arr <= 1500000
            Band = 4
        Case else
            Band = 5
    End Select
End Function
```